# Angular 5 - loading DataTables

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

i work with Angular 5 and datatables 1.10.12

I have simple configuration with routes :

```
 export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'documentlist',
        component: DocumentlistComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardEcm]
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

HomeComponent component shows datas using jQuery plug-in: DataTables

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare interface DataTable {
  headerRow: string[];
  footerRow: string[];
  dataRows: string[][];
}

declare const $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table-cmp',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public dataTable: DataTable;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Home - ngOnInit');
    this.dataTable = {
      headerRow: [ 'Nom', 'Position', 'Office', 'Age', 'Date', 'Actions' ],
      footerRow: [ 'Nom', 'Position', 'Office', 'Age', 'Start Date', 'Actions' ],

      dataRows: [
        ['Airi Satou', 'Andrew Mike', 'Develop', '2013', '99,225', ''],
        ['Angelica Ramos', 'John Doe', 'Design', '2012', '89,241', 'btn-round'],
        ['Ashton Cox', 'Alex Mike', 'Design', '2010', '92,144', 'btn-simple'],
        ['Bradley Greer', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
        ['Caesar Vance', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
        ['Cedric Kelly', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
        ['Charde Marshall', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
 etc...

      ]
    };

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Home - ngAfterViewInit');
    $('#datatables').DataTable({
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']],
      responsive: true,
      language: {
        lengthMenu: 'Afficher _MENU_ enregistrements par page',
        zeroRecords: 'Aucun enregistrement trouvé',
        info: 'Page _PAGE_ sur _PAGES_',
        infoEmpty: 'Aucun enre disponible',
        infoFiltered: '(filtré(s) sur _MAX_ enregistrements)',
        paginate: {
          first:      'Premier',
          last:       'dernier',
          next:       'Suivant',
          previous:   'Precedent'
        },
        search: '_INPUT_',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Recherche',
      }

    });

    const table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

  }
}
```

After login, table appears but without search bar and sort doesn't work...

[image]

but if I click on another link ("Documents" for example) and then I click on the main menu "Accueil", it work's :

[image]

I have no error in console...
How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this isn't THE solution you've been asking for, but maybe using the Angular Data Tables might yield better results for you. I say this, because I try to avoid jQuery as much as possible. While it's not inherently always possible to do, as some popular plugins are only available for jQuery, but there are nowadays great alternatives that have developed quite nicely.

- https://github.com/ggmod/angular-5-data-table Data Table
- https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid Slickgrid

Comment: Angular-Slickgrid is very interisting but i always get this error : ERROR Error: SlickGrid requires a valid container, #grid1 does not exist in the DOM.

Comment: @Anakin Hey, I tried it out. Works fine for me. I created a git project for you, so you can download it. It's minimal implementation only, so you can freely change stuff. I did the steps according to the how-to https://github.com/akleimrey/gridTablesDemo